# PHP - Creating CSV file inserts empty row at the end

Tags: php, csv, row

I am trying to create a CSV file in my php script. It creates the file but each time it inserts an empty row at the end.

My code is below:

```
$csv_output .= "Header 0,";
$csv_output .= "Header 1,";
$csv_output .= "Header 2,";
$csv_output .= "Header 3,";
$csv_output .= "Header 4,";
$csv_output .= "\r\n";

// db query...

foreach($rows as $row):

    if($row["value_3"] == 10)
    {
        $x = 'low';
    }
    else if($row["value_3"] == 100)
    {
        $x = 'high';
    }

    $csv_output .= "".$row["value_0"].",";
    $csv_output .= "".$row["value_1"].",";
    $csv_output .= "".$row["value_2"].",";
    $csv_output .= "".$x.",";
    $csv_output .= "Constant Always Value Goes here (not in db),";
    $csv_output .= "\r\n";
endforeach;

$filename = "csv_".date("d-m-Y_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;
```

No matter what my database query is or how many rows the csv contains there is always an empty row at the end. Is there anything causing this?

Comment: First rule of creating CSV files...... use PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function..... then it won't break your file if you have a comma (or other delimiter character) in your data

Comment: And why are you using those empty strings (`""`) before each value..... it's pointless and meaningless overhead

Comment: And if there's an empty row at the end, it's likely to be added ___after___ your `print $csv_output;` line

Comment: Why are you using `\r\n` as an EOL character, that may work on your windows box, but all *NIX like systems use `\n`. Thankfully, PHP has a magic constant `PHP_EOL` that depends on the platform

Comment: @MarkBaker How does fputcsv() work in this case, where it seems to me like he's not actually writing the CSV file somewhere as opposed to prompting a download of it? I thought fputcsv only worked with resources, and I wouldn't know where to start addressing this as a resource. Thanks :)

Comment: @LoganBentley - `php://output` is a resource.... the resource that corresponds with "send this to the browser" when working with the web sapi.... you'd simply move all yoru csv generation to after the headers, then fopen php://output for writing; fputcsv your array of values to that resource, and close it again when you'd finished looping..... pretty much exactly as @Flosculus has just posted

Comment: @MarkBaker interesting, never knew I could also access it that way. Thanks!

Comment: @LoganBentley - the weird one is accessing `php://input` using file functions to get the body of a POST request rather than the more regular $_POST approach

Comment: And reading `php://input` is pretty much mandatory for reading non-`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, like json, or xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the CSV directly to the output like so, and you don't need to format it yourself.

```
// Send correctly formatted headers
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

// Disposition should be "attachment" followed by optional filename.
header(sprintf('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="csv_%s.csv"', date("d-m-Y_H-i")));

// Open a pointer to the output stream
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// Build header array
$head = array(
    "Header 0",
    "Header 1",
    "Header 2",
    "Header 3"
);

// Write the header array in default csv row format.
fputcsv($fp, $head);

// db query...

// Loop rows
foreach($rows as $row) {
    // Write the rows in default csv row format
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}

// Close the output stream
fclose($fp);
```

An additional benefit is it will use less memory on large downloads, for instance with PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ...");
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
```

This will output each row to the browser, directly from the database (more or less), will a very low memory footprint.

Comment: Only 1 thing and sorry didn't put this in my original question (now in edited). Inside my for each loop - I need to check what the value is and put text inside the csv rather than the value for one of them (see in edit `if($row["value_3"] == 10) ...` And also when i'm wanting to put a constant string in there (see header 4 column) which isn;'t accessed from my db query but is always a constant value for every row. How would I do this with `fputcsv`?

Comment: @odd_duck You can modify the elements of `$row` inside the loop.  So to add a column at the end is: `$row[] = "My Constant Value"`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from other problems highlighted by Mark Baker, you are adding `EOL` in the loop. Remove the final one by [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

```
print trim($csv_output);
```